# Please wait while checking remote validators in parsley.js

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

I have a form with 10 fields. For 5 fields I use remote validation which takes few seconds. 
I need to show user Please Wait info and hide it when all remote validations are finished. 
Any smart way how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should listen to the `field:validate` event to display the "Please wait" notice and to the `field:validated` event to remove it.

More about Parsley events [here](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/#events).

Comment: Many thanks! . I did it like that, looks like it works fine : 
`app.validationCount=0; $.listen('parsley:field:validate',function(){
        app.validationCount++;
        $('#formSubmitButton').html('Please wait ...');
    });

    $.listen('parsley:field:validated',function(){
        app.validationCount--;
        if (app.validationCount==0){
          $('#formSubmitButton').html(app.buttonString);
        }
    });`

Comment: The github links are broken.

Comment: Can't expect a github `/blob/master/` being not broken after 2 years ;) Documentation still up to date though. Best